# Need to unlock Coby tablet; MicroSD card not formatted

Tags: locked-out

My Coby Kyros MID7024 tablet is locked with a pattern lock. The person who set the pattern lock has unfortunately forgotten it. I tried to unlock the tablet using these methods:

1. The volume adjustment buttons are broken, so it is no use to use them to reset my tablet.
2. When activated, the reset hole does not remove this pattern lock. Why?
3. I plugged my tablet to my laptop (before its USB ports broke) and tried to unlock the tablet with ADB (which can be found in the Android runtime and developer tools from Google). Unfortunately, I forgot to enable USB debugging just in case it ever got locked up.
4. My MicroSD card is not formatted right now, so I cannot download an app to unlock my tablet because I need to format the SD card before I put anything on it again.

I do not know of any other methods to unlock the tablet.

Comment: Never heard of it, but it looks to be an Android tablet. If so this question is off-topic here and will be migrated to android.SE for you.

Comment: usually that is unlockable using the google e-mail registered to google play. if you cant that way, it can be done using an adb session. **note: your question is offtopic in SU and will likely be moved.**